# Equal winding number implies two paths are path homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, winding-number

Let $\alpha,\beta:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\{p\}$ be two (continuous) paths (not necessarily closed) with same endpoints ($\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$, $\alpha(1)=\beta(1)$), we know that if $\alpha\simeq_\mathrm{p}\beta$, then $\mathrm{W}(\alpha,p)=\mathrm{W}(\beta,p)$ by using lifting lemma. However, is the converse also true? If so, how to construct a homotopy?

Comment: First, the winding number is not defined for non-closed paths, you need a loop for this. Second, you have to learn about the fundamental group of the circle and how to prove that it is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: No, the winding number can be defined for any path by lifting with respect to polar coordinate function; and for closed loop, it is indeed an integer.

Comment: Then you would surely need the added condition that $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$ and $\alpha(1)=\beta(1)$ and then talk about homotopies relative to end points.

Comment: yes, you're correct, my mistake:)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a possible proof:

Let $\overline{\alpha}$, $\overline{\beta}$ be the lifting of $\alpha$, $\beta$ such that $\overline{\alpha}(0)=\overline{\beta}(0)$, then $\mathrm{W}(\alpha,p)=\mathrm{W}(\beta,p)$ implies there is a path homotopy between $\overline{\alpha}$, $\overline{\beta}$, (both coordinate use path homotopy since they are paths in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times\mathbb{R}$). Then composite with function $(r,\theta)\mapsto r\exp(i\theta)$ would be a path homotopy between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.